# What happens for the last line when using N command with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

Here is my sed command:

```
echo -e "AB\nCD\nEF\nGH" | sed 'N; D;'
```

It prints:

```
GH
```

while `sed` processing input line by line, what happens with the last line? (When after that `sed` saw End-Of-File)? I mean the pattern buffer only contains 1 line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It halts processing. From the [sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands):

- `N` : Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space. If there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more commands.

So it never gets to the `D;`, and you're left with just the last `GH`.

Comment: But `N` does not effect `stdout`. we saw `GH` because we have not set `-n` option?

Comment: `N` does not effect `stdout` directly but as the answer quotes it makes `sed` abort processing before executing the `D` command hence the `GH` is left untouched and consequently printed.